# Checking Duplicate Value in each array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question. Let say I have three or more arrays:

```
[weekly] => Array (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 11:00
                        [1] => 11:00
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 13:00
                        [1] => 16:00
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 08:00
                        [1] => 12:00
                        [2] => 15:00
                    )
                ... 
              )
```

I tried to use array_unique() in foreach() loop but I can't catch that the first array has duplicate value. Actually, I would like to check if one of the array in the weekly array has a duplicate value and will return an error message that one of the arrays inside the weekly array has a duplicate value.

What is the proper checking of each sub-arrays of [weekly] that the first array has a duplicate value? I'm doing this using PHP.

Your answers will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something? Also what do you want to do if there are not duplicate values in the first sub array?

Comment: actually I tried to use array_unique in foreach loop but I can't catch that the first array has duplicate value. Actually, I would like to check if one of the array in the weekly array has a duplicate value.

Comment: ^ edit your question and add all these informations into your question. Also show, what you want to do if you find duplicate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to use array_unique() is not in a foreach loop.

```
<?php
 $input = array(4, "4", "3", 4, 3, "3");
 $result = array_unique($input);
 var_dump($result);
?>
```

Code taken from php documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

To see if there is a difference between two arrays, you can use count() after applying array_unique(). 
So, make a loop over a duplicate object, unique it out. Then check if the count is the same as the original within the same loop. 
This can be done in a more optimised way, but this is a start.